# Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/", null) in the _WidgetsAppState

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a `Flutter` app (Kinda a beginner here). Here is my code.
`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_timer/helpers/constants.dart';

void main() => runApp(ContactApp());

class ContactApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: appColor,
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

`constants.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Color appColor = Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0);

const appTitle = "Contact App";
```

When I run it in emulator, I get below exception message.

> I/flutter ( 7381): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY  ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 7381): The following assertion was thrown building IconTheme(IconThemeData#2abdc(color:
>   I/flutter ( 7381): Color(0xdd000000))):
>   I/flutter ( 7381): Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Do I need to add `Navigator` in `main.dart`? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have to use a property **home** or **initialRoute** to navigate to your initial screen to display to the users.

So, just add a home Property like, inside your MaterialApp

```
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: appColor,
      ),
      home: TestPage ()
    );
```

Create a screen or page to display to the users as following,

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text("Hello World!!"),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added routers and proper pages. It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()), (r) => false);
```